# Fetch DELETE method add unicode characters in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, fetch

I use fetch (in React) with the DELETE method, execute a query with line (api understands the given value)

```
name-%{[@timestamp]}-1970.01.01

fetch(`/api/apiname/name-%{[@timestamp]}-1970.01.01`, {
        method: 'delete',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Token}`
        }
    })
```

like this, but when requested, I get characters in query line

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/apiname/name-%%7B[@timestamp]%7D-1970.01.01
```

that prevent it from being executed, how can I fix this?

I tried to use **decodeURI** but it didn't help

P.S. I need the request to be

```
http://localhost:3000/api/apiname/name-%{[@timestamp]}-1970.01.01
```

but not

```
http://localhost:3000/api/apiname/name-%%7B[@timestamp]%7D-1970.01.01
```

Comment: _"I tried to use decodeURI but it didn't help"_ - how should it, _where_ would you even apply that? It is obviously fetch/the browser itself, that added the encoding - so what would using decodeURI _anywhere_ achieve here, as soon as you pass the value to fetch, the same thing will happen again.

Comment: You could try and create your own `Request` object first, and then pass that to fetch - but I would expect, that the automatic application of URL encoding will probably happen there the same way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: But this issue should really rather get fixed on the receiving end, if at all possible. URL encoding is a _standard_, that any application that pretends to "speak HTTP" should support. If it doesn't, it should be considered broken in that regard.

Comment: I tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request but the result is the same as it was. Thanks for the answer